# WCF Web Service needs access to user name and password information

Tags: wcf, service, passwords, web

I have build a wcf web service that simply provides MS Dynamics SQL data to a CRM hosted Silverlight application.  Currently the web services are hosted in IIS and are only available via HTTPS so the contents of the messages are secure.  I'm now ready to implement the next level of security that has to do with who is logged into the Silverlight client application.  I'd like to pass that information to the web service and then use it when creating the SQL Server Connection object.  The results will be that the MS Dynamics Database will then only return data that the connected user is authorized to view.

This model is different from the standard model that consists of authenticating a given user for access to the web service.  Instead, in my model everyone is granted access to the web service and the results of the SQL queries are based on the user name and password for a given user.

**For Clarification:** The Silverlight application collects the user name and password from the user when they log on to the application.  This is the information that eventually needs to be used by the web service when the web service makes the connection to the SQL Server database.  So my goal is to have the Silverlight applicaiton pass the username and password to the web service in such a way that the web service can retrieve it and use it when creating the Connection object.

I'm considering something as simple as adding the user name and password to each web service request.  However I'd rather be able to use the standard method for passing user credentials but I can't seem to find any way to get to the password.  The user name is accessable throught the OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should clarify what user name and password do you want to pass. Isn't access to CRM restricted only for Windows accounts? Is your Silverlight application accessed within intranet by domain users? Is user authenticated by his domain account in your service?

Comment: To clarify - Bob Jones is logged into CRM.  I need Bob Jones user name and password in the Web Service.  The Web Service is hosted in the cloud and uses the user name and password to then create a connection to the database hosted on yet another server.  Currently the web service uses a default user name and password to connect to the database and I want to use Bob Jones instead.

Comment: Is Bob Jones Windows account? Btw. No build in security mechanism will get you password within operation processing. Do you need to create connection using SQL credentials or windows credentials?

Comment: Bob Jones is not a windows account.  The connection needs to be made with SQL credentials.  As I suggested, I'm considering making the username and password parameters of each web service method but I'd rather not if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [wsHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731299.aspx) for passing credentials to your service, this will however at the very least require you to send the credentials with message security. You can combine this with anonymous authentication in IIS. This way, everyone can access the service on a transport level, but you'll be able to handle the credentials yourself.

To expand, I have a WCF service running in IIS with HTTPS and anonymous authentication. In my web.config I've set up a wsHttpBinding, like this:

```
<bindings>
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="CredentialsBinding" />
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

In my behaviors, I've set up a servicebehavior for a custom username/password validator, like so:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication
        userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
       customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyNamespace.CredentialValidator, MyNamespace"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
       </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

The validator looks like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace.CredentialValidator
{
    public class CredentialValidator:  UserNamePasswordValidator 
    {
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            // you can now handle the username and password passed to your service
            // with a wsHttpBinding through HTTPS
        }
    }
}
```

--EDIT

Rory Primrose describes what you're probably looking for in his article [WCF Security: Getting the password of the user](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2008/04/07/wcf-security-getting-the-password-of-the-user.aspx), using a CustomUserNameSecurityTokenAuthenticator to get the password for further use.

Comment: Thanks for the direction - do you have an example?

Comment: The research I have done to date indicates that the user name is available but that the password is a hidden secret.

Comment: I'm aware of this but it's not my solution as this happens prior to my web service method being called.  I need the same information inside of my web service methods.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand completely. Why do you need the password after authentication has taken place? You can authenticate up front with your database credentials. If it fails, throw an exception, otherwise proceed.

In your actual method you are now authenticated and can determine whatever authorization you want to with the username?

Comment: Did you read paragraph two of my original post?  I am fully aware of what I can do with up front authentication.  However, this isn't my requirement.  The silverlight application is open to the world.  The user provides user name and password which are the credentials needed for the SQL server access.  The Silverlight application makes requests from the web service (and needs to pass the user's credentials which they provided) to the web service.  The web service then needs to use the user name and password when creating the SQL server connection object for access to the SQL server database.

Comment: Yes, I did read the second paragraph, but "the results of the SQL queries are based on the user name and password for a given user" is pretty ambiguous, part of your first comment should be probably be moved to your question for clarification.